# R Markdown Template for US Patents

Tags: library, r, templating

I am looking for a R package to help me *format* my patent. I can use regular [R Markdown](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/pdf-document.html#advanced-customization-1) and wire up the TxT package [uspatent](https://ctan.org/pkg/uspatent), but I am looking for a more integrated solution. Similar to how [rticles](https://github.com/rstudio/rticles) works for academic journals. I have all my text and images already.